# What is the highest DPS plant?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I was wondering lately what plant had the highest DPS.
I was thinking about this because I might make a mod for it, and I want to know which plants might need a slight nerf.
But of course, for some bizarre reason, the wiki doesn't seem to have a page for it!
What plants have the highest DPS?

Comment: I do not consider instant-kills most of the time due to the long recharge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some of the highest DPS plants that **do not** have a long recharge:

- Winter Melon: 80 DPS with slow.
- Melon Pult: 80 DPS.
- Gloom Shrooms: 80 DPS.
- Gatling Pea: 80 DPS (with Torchwood:160 DPS and splash).

I will keep updating my list as I find more plants with high DPS.

Comment: Hello everyone, I don't know the splash damage of the gatling pea torchwood combo so if one of you know and can tell me that would be great!

Comment: What about Cattail? They're pretty good damage-wise.

Comment: I guess you could say their range is good but their DPS is a mediocre amount ( 40 DPS ). But I guess I can agree with you.

Comment: I guess that makes Cattail solely anti balloons, and their damage is just a bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Cob Cannon would have the highest DPS then.
Once the corn cob is produced, the player can click on the Cob Cannon and can manually launch the corn cob onto an area that the player targets. The corn cob will explode and deal 1800 damage to all zombies in a 3x3 area, like the Cherry Bomb.

Comment: If we count Cob Cannon, shouldn't we also count the other insta-kill plants such as Cherry Bomb and Jalapeno since they deal equivalent damage? Cob Cannon is functionally a reuseable Cherry Bomb.

Comment: Don't forget the doom shroom, potato mine, tangle kelp, and squash!

Comment: I agree, they all have different affects and kinda 1 hit zombies. These types of plants can be usefull against gargantuars. They have different reload times. So all these plants you guys are stating are very usefull! Also high in damage. So we should count them aswell.

Comment: @Don'tKillTheChicken, you might have a different version then me, as all my instant kills have the same reload time.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Melon Pult's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/378855/57616) is the way to go. Do consider also that for masses of zombies coming onto you (in Survival and Last Stand), splash or area damage may cause a weak plant to be dealing more damage than a stronger one.

The wiki says that [Spikeweed](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Spikeweed_(PvZ)) will do damage to a single zombie at a rate about 4/3 that of a peashooter. A peashooter will do 20 points of damage per shot, so a Spikeweed would be doing ~26 damage per tick.

Against a single zombie, a Gatling Pea without the aid of a Torchwood will do 80 DPS, which is practically 3x the damage that a Spikeweed could do. But if you have 10 zombies stepping on it at the same time, the Spikeweed will be dishing about 260 DPS, and it will bypass screen-door shields. A Spikerock would be dealing 520 DPS total!

So you might also with to consider nerfing Spikeweed and Spikerock.

Answer (score 0):

DPS is but one of many characteristics.  Damage per tile moved seems more useful.  If a fast-moving zombie is coming at you, DPS doesn't help much unless it kills them.  But, if you can slow or stop them, then you gain time.

Another statistic is cost.  The little tiny mushrooms do little damage, but they are free, and need to be eaten (most of the time) and thus will slow zombies a little.

For example, the watermelon slows enemies, thus creating more damage per tile moved.  Same with the spikeweed, and other things also slow or stop them.

On levels with a lot of zombies, plants that can damage more than one zombie gain more use.

Depending on which PvZ game, Hypnoshroom can do the most damage, if it gets eaten by a powerful zombie.

Damage per:

1. second
2. tile
3. cost
4. total zombies on the board
5. slow, insta-kill, etc...

Comment: Well, if you slow or stop them you do gain time, but **DPS does matter a ton and also the post asks about DPS.**

Comment: I agree with Penguin: you answer based on your interpretation of the reason the OP asks for the highest DPS stat, but they simply want to know what the plant with the highest DPS is.

Comment: @MikeP spikeweed only damages zombies, not slows them. By the way, are your talking about winter melon or melon pult when you say "watermelon"? P.S. the tiny little mushrooms are called puff shrooms.

Comment: The fastest moving zombie is the dolphin rider, which takes around 1-2 seconds a tile and will slow down to around 4-5 seconds a tile after jumping over a plant. His HP is 200.